# I dont know how to stop my tower from attacking in a tower defence game, someone helped me with a functions canAttack and attack, but i dont know how

Tags: python, pygame

The aim is to implement a cooldown system so that my tower doesn't attack as many times as possible without stopping the whole program, as i said `canAttack` and attack functions were given to me by someone else but i do not know how to use them in my classes in order to fix the cooldown, I do not have any projectiles just collisions trigger the attacks sorry for the long code but its all necessary. I have tried and failed and my attempt is still there.

```
import sys
import pygame
import threading

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT= 600


RED = (150, 0, 0)
LRED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 150, 0)
LGREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 150)
LBLUE = (0, 0, 255)
CYAN=(0x00, 0xff, 0xff)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (150, 0, 150)
LPURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
COLORS = [RED, LRED, GREEN, LGREEN, BLUE, LBLUE, WHITE, PURPLE, LPURPLE]

pygame.init()
Mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()


action_box_image = pygame.image.load('goku.png')
fantower_image = pygame.image.load('saibaman1.png')

class Tower:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "goku.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.next_attack_time = 0

    COOLDOWN = 1200

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

    def canAttack( self ):
        """ Has the attack cooldown-period expired """
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_attack_time ):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def attack( self, opponent ):
        """ The tower is attacking the opponent """
        if ( self.canAttack() ):
            self.next_attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + Tower.COOLDOWN
            ### TODO: Whatever needs to be done for an attack
            ### Maybe create and return a projectile, change the Tower image, etc.
            return True  # New projectile, whatever
        else:
            return None  # Cooldown is still running; no attack


    

class Tower2:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "invis.png" )
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.next_attack_time = 0

    COOLDOWN = 1200
    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

    def canAttack( self ):
        """ Has the attack cooldown-period expired """
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_attack_time ):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def attack( self, opponent ):
        """ The tower is attacking the opponent """
        if ( self.canAttack() ):
            self.next_attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + Tower.COOLDOWN
            ### TODO: Whatever needs to be done for an attack
            ### Maybe create and return a projectile, change the Tower image, etc.
            return True  # New projectile, whatever
        else:
            return None  # Cooldown is still running; no attack

    
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.dead = False
        self.dir = 4
        self.movement = [(810, 100, 2), (810, 350, 4), (620, 350, 8), (620, 275, 4), (410, 275, 2), (410, 350, 4), (298, 350, 2), (298, 450, 4), (80, 450, 8), (80, 350, 4)]
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "saibaman1.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        self.health = 50

     def move(self): 
        if self.dir == 8:
             self.rect.centery -= 1
        if self.dir == 4:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        if self.dir == 6:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.dir == 2:
            self.rect.centery += 1

    def update(self):
        for pos in self.movement:
            if self.rect.center == (pos[0], pos[1]):
                self.dir = pos[2]

    def color(self, colorid):
        return COLORS[colorid]

    def die( self, action=True ):
        self.dead = action

    def isDead( self ):
        return self.dead

    def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
        """ Return true, if other_rect overlaps my rect """
        return self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

def button_tower(x, y, width, height, mouse, click, image, action = None):
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            MainWindow.action_box = action

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button_text(msg, x, y, width, height, mouselse, mouseover, action = None, Text = True):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouseover,(x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouselse,(x,y,width,height))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)))
    MainWindow.Gamewindow.blit(textSurf, textRect)


class Main:

    def __init__(self, width = WIDTH+100, height = HEIGHT + 100):
        pygame.display.set_caption('DBZ Tower Defense')
        self.startwave = False
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.Gamewindow = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        # Load images
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.image.load( "Kami_lookout.png" ).convert_alpha() 
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.light_image_map1, ( width, height ) )
        self.background_rectangle = self.light_image_map1.get_rect()
        self.background_rectangle.topleft = (0,0)


    def wave(self):
        self.startwave = True

    def Intro(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.Gamewindow.fill(BLACK)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("simple tower defense game", largeText)
            TextRect = (100, 100)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            button_text("New game", 100, 200, 400, 50, GREEN, LGREEN, MainWindow.MainLoop)
            button_text("Continue", 100, 300, 400, 50, RED, LRED)
            button_text("Exit", 100, 400, 400, 50, BLUE, LBLUE, quit)
            pygame.display.update()


    def MainLoop(self):
        self.enemy = []
        self.tower = []
        self.action_box = None

        self.startwave = True   # Don't have button code, force start

        while True:
            Mainclock.tick(60)
        
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
                    # create a tower where the mouse was clicked
                    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                    self.tower.append( Tower( mouse[0], mouse[1], 64, 64 ) )
                    self.tower.append( Tower2( mouse[0], mouse[1], 150, 150 ) )
            
            if self.startwave == True and len(self.enemy)==0:
                self.wave(10, 20, 8) 
                self.startwave = False
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                self.enemy[i].update()
                self.enemy[i].move()
                if ( self.enemy[i].rect.left <= 0 ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )
        
            self.Gamewindow.fill(CYAN)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(self.light_image_map1, self.background_rectangle)
            #button_tower(800, 0, 50, 50, self.mouse, self.click, fantower_image, tower)

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.action_box != None:
                rectangle30 = pygame.Rect(self.mouse[0]-15, self.mouse[1]-15, 30, 30)
                self.Gamewindow.blit(action_box_image, rectangle30)
            elif self.action_box != None:
                self.action_box()
                self.action_box = None

            for object_enemy in self.enemy:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_enemy.image, object_enemy.rect)
            for object_tower in self.tower:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_tower.image, object_tower.rect)

            button_text("Start next wave", 0, 600, WIDTH, 100, PURPLE, LPURPLE, MainWindow.wave)
            ll = 0
        
            for tower in self.tower:
                for enemy in self.enemy:
                    if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) and Tower2.canAttack(self)):
                        # Make enemy dead
                        print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
                        #ll = ll + 1
                        #if ll > 2:
                        if enemy.health != 0:
                            enemy.health = enemy.health - 1
                        else: enemy.die()
                            #ll = 0
                        pp = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                        print(pp)
                    
                    
                    
                        
                    
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                if ( self.enemy[i].isDead() ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )

            pygame.display.update()

    def wave( self, quantity, size, distance):    # <<-- Made member function of MainWindow
        global saiba
        hh = True
        for i in range(quantity):
            saiba = Enemy(800 + (distance + size)*i, 100- size/2, size, size)
            self.enemy.append(saiba)


# MAIN
MainWindow = Main()
MainWindow.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's a couple of issues:

The first is that the code is calling against the "definition" of the tower function (`Tower2.canAttack()`), rather than on an instance "live copy" of a tower (`tower.canAttack()`).

```
for tower in self.tower:
    for enemy in self.enemy:
        if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) and Tower2.canAttack(self)):   # <<-- HERE
            # Make enemy dead
            print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
```

Replacing this with the instance of the object fixes it:

```
for tower in self.tower:
    for enemy in self.enemy:
        if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) and tower.canAttack()):   # <<-- HERE
            # Make enemy dead
            print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
```

The difference is that the `Tower2` is like the "template" of the object, you kind-of make a "live copy" of the object - known as an "instance".  This is what the constructor does (via calling `Tower2.__init__()`)~

```
my_tower = Tower2( 10, 10, 64, 64 )
```

In the above line, `my_tower` is an *instance* of `Tower2`.  So generally you use `my_tower` once it's constructed.  There are circumstances when you might cal functions on the class definition ("staic functions") but that's beyond the scope of this answer.  Stick to your `my_tower` instance for now.

So the second issue, is that the cooldown is a 2-step process.  Once you check to see if the `tower` can make an attack with `tower.canAttack()`, then you need to register that the attack happened with `tower.attack( enemy )`.  Adding this (and some debug) into the code makes the cooldown work.

```
            for tower in self.tower:
                for enemy in self.enemy:
                    if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) ):
                        if ( tower.canAttack()):
                            tower.attack( enemy )        # <<-- HERE, note attack time
                            # Make enemy dead
                            print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
                            ### code omitted for brevity
                        else:
                            print( "tower can't attack (cooldown)" );
```

Calling `.attack(enemy)` calculates the next allowed attack time, so without it it's always valid to attack.

```
import sys
import pygame
import threading

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT= 600


RED = (150, 0, 0)
LRED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 150, 0)
LGREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 150)
LBLUE = (0, 0, 255)
CYAN=(0x00, 0xff, 0xff)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (150, 0, 150)
LPURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
COLORS = [RED, LRED, GREEN, LGREEN, BLUE, LBLUE, WHITE, PURPLE, LPURPLE]

pygame.init()
Mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()


action_box_image = pygame.image.load('tower1.png')
fantower_image = pygame.image.load('tower2.png')

class Tower:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "tower1.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.next_attack_time = 0

    COOLDOWN = 1200

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

    def canAttack( self ):
        """ Has the attack cooldown-period expired """
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_attack_time ):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def attack( self, opponent ):
        """ The tower is attacking the opponent """
        if ( self.canAttack() ):
            self.next_attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + Tower.COOLDOWN
            ### TODO: Whatever needs to be done for an attack
            ### Maybe create and return a projectile, change the Tower image, etc.
            return True  # New projectile, whatever
        else:
            return None  # Cooldown is still running; no attack


    

class Tower2:
    COOLDOWN = 1200

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "Castle.png" )
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        self.next_attack_time = 0

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

    def canAttack( self ):
        """ Has the attack cooldown-period expired """
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_attack_time ):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def attack( self, opponent ):
        """ The tower is attacking the opponent """
        if ( self.canAttack() ):
            self.next_attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + Tower.COOLDOWN
            ### TODO: Whatever needs to be done for an attack
            return True  # New projectile, whatever
        else:
            return False  # Cooldown is still running; no attack

    
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.dead = False
        self.dir = 4
        self.movement = [(810, 100, 2), (810, 350, 4), (620, 350, 8), (620, 275, 4), (410, 275, 2), (410, 350, 4), (298, 350, 2), (298, 450, 4), (80, 450, 8), (80, 350, 4)]
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "tower2.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        self.health = 50

    def move(self): 
        if self.dir == 8:
             self.rect.centery -= 1
        if self.dir == 4:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        if self.dir == 6:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.dir == 2:
            self.rect.centery += 1

    def update(self):
        for pos in self.movement:
            if self.rect.center == (pos[0], pos[1]):
                self.dir = pos[2]

    def color(self, colorid):
        return COLORS[colorid]

    def die( self, action=True ):
        self.dead = action

    def isDead( self ):
        return self.dead

    def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
        """ Return true, if other_rect overlaps my rect """
        return self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

def button_tower(x, y, width, height, mouse, click, image, action = None):
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            MainWindow.action_box = action

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button_text(msg, x, y, width, height, mouselse, mouseover, action = None, Text = True):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouseover,(x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouselse,(x,y,width,height))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)))
    MainWindow.Gamewindow.blit(textSurf, textRect)


class Main:

    def __init__(self, width = WIDTH+100, height = HEIGHT + 100):
        pygame.display.set_caption('DBZ Tower Defense')
        self.startwave = False
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.Gamewindow = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        # Load images
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.image.load( "background.png" ).convert_alpha() 
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.light_image_map1, ( width, height ) )
        self.background_rectangle = self.light_image_map1.get_rect()
        self.background_rectangle.topleft = (0,0)


    def wave(self):
        self.startwave = True

    def Intro(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.Gamewindow.fill(BLACK)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("simple tower defense game", largeText)
            TextRect = (100, 100)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            button_text("New game", 100, 200, 400, 50, GREEN, LGREEN, MainWindow.MainLoop)
            button_text("Continue", 100, 300, 400, 50, RED, LRED)
            button_text("Exit", 100, 400, 400, 50, BLUE, LBLUE, quit)
            pygame.display.update()


    def MainLoop(self):
        self.enemy = []
        self.tower = []
        self.action_box = None

        self.startwave = True   # Don't have button code, force start

        while True:
            Mainclock.tick(60)
        
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
                    # create a tower where the mouse was clicked
                    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                    self.tower.append( Tower( mouse[0], mouse[1], 64, 64 ) )
                    self.tower.append( Tower2( mouse[0], mouse[1], 150, 150 ) )
            
            if self.startwave == True and len(self.enemy)==0:
                self.wave(10, 20, 8) 
                self.startwave = False
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                self.enemy[i].update()
                self.enemy[i].move()
                if ( self.enemy[i].rect.left <= 0 ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )
        
            self.Gamewindow.fill(CYAN)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(self.light_image_map1, self.background_rectangle)
            #button_tower(800, 0, 50, 50, self.mouse, self.click, fantower_image, tower)

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.action_box != None:
                rectangle30 = pygame.Rect(self.mouse[0]-15, self.mouse[1]-15, 30, 30)
                self.Gamewindow.blit(action_box_image, rectangle30)
            elif self.action_box != None:
                self.action_box()
                self.action_box = None

            for object_enemy in self.enemy:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_enemy.image, object_enemy.rect)
            for object_tower in self.tower:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_tower.image, object_tower.rect)

            button_text("Start next wave", 0, 600, WIDTH, 100, PURPLE, LPURPLE, MainWindow.wave)
            ll = 0
        
            for tower in self.tower:
                for enemy in self.enemy:
                    if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) ):
                        if ( tower.canAttack()):
                            tower.attack( enemy )
                            # Make enemy dead
                            print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
                            #ll = ll + 1
                            #if ll > 2:
                            if enemy.health != 0:
                                enemy.health = enemy.health - 1
                            else: enemy.die()
                                #ll = 0
                            pp = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                            print(pp)
                        else:
                            print( "tower can't attack (cooldown)" );
                        
                        
                    
                        
                    
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                if ( self.enemy[i].isDead() ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )

            pygame.display.update()

    def wave( self, quantity, size, distance):    # <<-- Made member function of MainWindow
        global saiba
        hh = True
        for i in range(quantity):
            saiba = Enemy(800 + (distance + size)*i, 100- size/2, size, size)
            self.enemy.append(saiba)


# MAIN
MainWindow = Main()
MainWindow.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the COOLDOWN variables in the Tower classes are set to 1200. Since milliseconds are used by pygame.time.get_ticks(), this 1200 means 1.2 seconds. So if you want the cooldown to be longer, increase the COOLDOWN variables and see if that helps.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, i didn't ask how to increase the cooldown i asked how i can get the cooldown to work

Comment: @omzy54 how often does your tower attack right now? Like how many seconds does it wait between each attack.

Comment: it doesnt wait at all it just keeps attacking forever as long as the code is running, thats what im trying to stop

Comment: @omzy54 What I'm wondering if it fires around every second, continuously. If so, it's essentially "stopping" for 1 second before firing again. Which is why I suggested increasing the 1200 value to see if that helped. It might look like it's attacking forever when it's actually already using a 1 second "cooldown".

Comment: it fires multiple times a second